# Remove slash str_replace PHP

Tags: php, str-replace

im trying to remove the unwanted characters from a string, but i cannot figure out with the slash / one.

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/";
$array_remove = array(
  '/',
  ' ',
  '-',
  '.'  
);

$string = "This i Will convert to-Picture/sting";

$convert = $url.'images/'.strtolower(str_replace($array_remove, '_',$string).'.gif');
```

in this case the slash will remain there and the result will be: `this_i_will_convert_to_picture/string.gif`

But need to be `this_i_will_convert_to_picture_string.gif`

Any help or hint here is very well appreciated.

Comment: Is giving me the slash i have tried also "\/" , '\/', '/', '\\', and is still there :(.

Comment: Died you tried use single-qoutes in the definition line like that $string = 'bla' ? Maybe \s means something on your system for some reason? Conversion is working on writecodeonline.com by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly in Version 5.4.0.
Try preg_replace:

```
  $string = preg_replace('(\/)', '_', $string);  
  echo "<br />string:".$string."<br />";
```

Are you maybe fetching the data from a POST?

Answer (score 0):

The conversion dont want to work in this scenario, so i changed the scenario to save the final string and use there where i want.

Is the same thing, but in this scenario work.

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/";
$array_remove = array(
  '/',
  ' ',
  '-',
  '.'  
);
$string = "This i Will convert to-Picture/sting";
$converted = strtolower(str_replace($array_remove, '_', $string));

$convert = $url.'images/'.$converted.'.gif';
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellent! Your code works perfectly.
Run this code:

```
 $url = "http://www.google.com/";
 $array_remove = array( '/', ' ',  '-',  '.'  );
 $string = "This i Will convert to-Picture/sting";
 echo "string: ".$string."<br />";
 $converted = strtolower(str_replace($array_remove, '_', $string));
 echo "converted: ".$converted."<br />";
 $convert = $url.'images/'.$converted.'.gif';
 echo "convert: ".$convert."<br />";
```

and your output should be:

string: This i Will convert to-Picture/sting
converted: this_i_will_convert_to_picture_sting
convert: http://www.google.com/images/this_i_will_convert_to_picture_sting.gif

or what output are you getting?